# Cannot find "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" permission in Xamarin android code. I need to check if user has Granted this permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions, android-location

I am trying to check if user has selected "Allow only while app is use" option when Location permission is asked on Android-10 devices in Xamarin.

I have updated my android sdk to the latest and also updated the visual studio with all other mono packages.I have tried setting the target version to Api 29(Android 10) but still no luck.

In native Android code(JAVA or Kotlin)it is simple and available like,

val hasBackgroundLocationPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

I want to achieve the same in Xamarin android(C#)

I am expecting that I should get this permission(ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)in code.
But I don't see this is available yet in Xamarin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** is new after Android 10.0 . Even if you have set the target version to Api 29 , but the version of support SDK in Xamarin.Android is still v28.x.x.x (Android 9.0) .So this enumeration is still unavailable in Xamarin.Android now . What you need is just to wait the update of the support SDK .

[image]

In your case , **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** will compatible with old version .
If the application apply for **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** or **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**, the system will automatically add a permission **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** during building.

Similarly, if an application requests **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** or **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**, the system automatically adds **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** to the request.

Comment: I think this would be the answer to my question. Any idea about when does the Microsoft gives update to this support library? any link to the pre-release notes?

Comment: Will they provide update on v28.0.0.3 or we need to migrate on AndroidX ?

Comment: You can mark my post as answer if it helps you to solve the issue .

Comment: this answer is wrong, yet used on everybody asking this question. ref. official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx
No more support is given to this package, it will never be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution for the exact same thing which is something as follows:

In your OnCreate method check for existing permissions:

```
 if (!(CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) 
         &&(CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation) 
         && CheckPermissionGranted(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)))
        {
            RequestLocationPermission();
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeLocationManager();
        }
        InitPageWidgets();
```

Where Check permission Granted is a method something like this:

```
 [Export]
    public bool CheckPermissionGranted(string Permissions)
    {
        // Check if the permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Permissions) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

And the Request permission code looks something like this:

```
  private void RequestLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
        {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }
        else
        {
            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, PermissionsLocation, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Once you accept or reject this permission this method will get called:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions,
                     Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == RequestPermissionsRequestCode)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length <= 0)
            {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.Info(Tag, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            }
            else if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PermissionGranted)
            {
                // Permission was granted.

            }
            else
            {
                // Permission denied.

                Toast.MakeText(this, "Permission Denied", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note that this is only available in the latest version of Xamarin with VS 2019**

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to handle the permissions on the Xamarin platform. Something like:

```
await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
                {
                    ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                    AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                    DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                    DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                    DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                    PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                });
```

I'm not a pro in Xamarin but I think this could be a solution for you and with this plugin also you can check if the user grants the permissions or not

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I need to use "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" this particular permission in code